# Looking for a certain function with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

can someone help me with the following doubt?

I know that if we consider a function $f$ with compact support and $C^\infty(\mathbb{R^2})$ such  that $f(x)=1$ if $|x|\leq{1}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $|x|\geq{3}$. Then  $f_s(x)=f(\frac{x}{s})$ with $s>0$ verifies $$\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}{f_s(x)}=1$$

How can we define $f_s(x)$ to get $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}{f_s(x)}=|x|^2$?

I thought of considering $f(x)=|x|^2$ if $|x|\leq{1}$ and $f(x)=0$ if $|x|\geq{3}$ and using $f_s$ as before, but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will work.
$$
\lim_{s\to\infty}f_s(x)=f(0)
$$
is a constant.

Comment: And $f_s(x)=f(\frac{x}{s})|x|^2$?

Comment: The limit will be $f(0)\,|x|^2$.

Comment: But un muy cuestión $f(0)=1$

Comment: Then $f(0)\,|x|^2=|x|^2$.

Comment: In that definition $f_s(x)$ has also compact support and is infinite derivable?